# Running Code From A Particular Context After A Form Closes?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to run some code in this context after the form created here closes.

```
Form1 Form1 = new Form1();
Form1.Show(); //<-After this closes, I want to run code from this context, using ShowDialog() is not an option
```

Comment: Handle the Hide and/or Closing events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just register for the `FormClosing` event of the `Form`

```
void MyClosingEvent(object o, FormClosingEventArgs args)
{
}

private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    form1.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(MyClosingEvent);
    //Or if you have C# 2 or higher: 
    //form1.FormClosing += MyClosingEvent;
```

Comment: But the code needs to be executed from the context in which the form was created.  There's a method in that context that I don't know how to trigger in the form without passing the first form as a parameter when the second form is being created...

Comment: @Soo then make that method public or make another method that calls that method public.

Comment: @Soo or else register for the event inside of the Form1 if you prefer.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your answer before you posted that code example.  Thanks, I implemented your suggestion :)